# calculating Total Length of stay for a bed occupancy rate Formula in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

we have a table named PatientAdmissions listed below [image]

I'm trying to get the Total Length of stay which is the Total Date difference between the AdmitDate and the DischargeDate in a provided period of time from the user by (AdmitDate as FromDate,DischargeDate as ToDate) 
and then apply the following formula 
[image]

and the Number of Days in the period would be AdmitDate as FromDate and DischargeDate as ToDate 
, I couldn't figure out a way to write the query without getting any e error's

Comment: [Forum Etiquette: how to post sample data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). What is your expected result, what have you tried so far? If you're getting errors, what are those errors?

Comment: Total Length of stay which is the Total Date difference between the AdmitDate and the DischargeDate in a provided period of time means in `hours` ?? Or What??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(hour, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) AS 'Total Length of stay',
DATEDIFF(day, AdmitDate, DischargeDate) AS 'Number of Days in the period',
(DATEDIFF(hour, AdmitDate, DischargeDate)*100)/(133*DATEDIFF(day, AdmitDate, DischargeDate))
AS Formula
from TableName
```

The `DATEDIFF()` function returns the difference between two date values, based on the interval specified.

**Syntax:** `DATEDIFF(Interval, date1, date2)`

- year, yyyy, yy = Year
- quarter, qq, q = Quarter
- month, mm, m = month
- dayofyear = Day of the year
- day, dy, y = Day
- week, ww, wk = Week
- weekday, dw, w = Weekday
- hour, hh = hour
- minute, mi, n = Minute
- second, ss, s = Second
- millisecond, ms = Millisecond

Comment: Please try to explain what your answer does. The person asking the question might not know what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (DATEDIFF(minute, AdmitDate , DischargeDate ))/133*(DATEDIFF(day, AdmitDate , DischargeDate )*100) from PatientAdmissions